# Yii 2 can rewrite WHERE condition from model?

Tags: sql, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have some where condition in my model .
Its check is field active or no.

Now I need to write a join relation. But I need to remove where condition. Is it possible?

My model.

```
  ...
  public static function find() {
     return (new AssetgroupsQuery(get_called_class()))->active();
  }
```

My relation

```
public function getAssetgroup(): \app\models\AssetgroupsQuery {
    return $this->hasOne(Assetgroups::class, ['asg_id' => 'ass_group'])->andOnCondition(['asg_active' => '1'])
        ->viaTable('assets', ['ass_id' => 'log_ass_id',]);
}
```

I need to got all active assets and join, if asset is empty I need to got null fields, but 
model where condition added to my current sql query and remove all fields which assets are null.
I try to add some where Condition to remove old where, but it don't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to do, can you show us the code where you are calling the above mentioned relation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset existing conditions by using `where(null)`.

On relation level:

```
public function getAssetgroup(): \app\models\AssetgroupsQuery {
    return $this->hasOne(Assetgroups::class, ['asg_id' => 'ass_group'])
        ->andOnCondition(['asg_active' => '1'])
        ->where(null)
        ->viaTable('assets', ['ass_id' => 'log_ass_id',]);
}
```

Or directly on join:

```
$query = MyModel::find()
    ->joinWith([
        'assetgroup' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->where(null);
        },
    ])
```

Comment: I use  -> where([]) , but I'm not sure that it's right.
Using null is better way?
What's the better way in model or in controller?

Comment: Empty array may also work, but `null` explicitly means "no where conditions", so I suggest using it as in my example.